# Stripe Checkout and Customer Creation

Tags: stripe-payments

I was having some difficulties figuring out how to add a customer and card with no charge to Stripe using the API where I *think* I came across a solution that seems to work but am not sure if I am creating issues that I cannot see.

What I am doing is using the Checkout option with strip and in my charge.php file I am deleting the below code so that no charge is made:

```
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  'customer' => $customer->id,
  'amount'   => 5000,
  'currency' => 'usd'
  ));
```

I am only keeping the below code:

```
  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  'email' => 'customer@example.com',
  'source'  => $token
  ));
```

As far as I can tell, the customer is being created, I can use that customer data to charge the card in the future and no charge is being made to the card when they submit the form.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you wanting to simply store the customer and card (for later charging)?

Comment: Affirmative. I tried to figure out how the api works but could not figure it out. Am not a programmer. Am basically a novice at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation here https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later - it's possible to store the customer's card details for a future date.

Using the following will store the customer and their card details for later:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'email'   => 'customer@example.com',
    'source'  => $token
));
```

Nothing else is needed. When you get ready to charge the customer in the future, you'll fetch their data (via their customer ID), and then run the following code:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    'amount'   => 9999,
    'currency' => 'usd'
));
```